# parameterize the count of input file rows in azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

1. I have input file as csv now i want to generate valid and invalid records as csv with same input file name as output file in azure data flow,
2. Now i want to get the count of valid and invalid records as parameter value by using azure data factory data flow.

Please suggest the way for both requirements.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data?

Comment: File Name is "Cust_04112023.csv"customer_id validation
1 Valid
2 Invalid
3 Valid
4 Invalid
5 Valid
6 Invalid
7 Valid
8 Invalid
9 Valid
10 Invalid " Here i want to generate invalid data with same file name and 2nd requirement is count of total records, valid and invalid records count need as parameter value"

Comment: you want to the count total records and store anywhere or just know the count of total records?

Answer (score 0):

I have csv file in my blob storage named "dbo.Customer.csv"

[image]

Created dataset with above data in data flow and added that as source in dataflow, added derived column activity to the source and created two new columns named "Validation" with value `iif(Id % 2 == 0, 'InValid', 'Valid')` and filename with "dbo.Customer.csv"

[image]

Added window activity to count the validation count and selected `Validation` column in `over` tab and created windows column named `validation_count` with value `count(Valdation)`

[image]

Added sink to the windows activity selected same dataset which selected to the source and selected file Name option as "Name file as column data" and selected "filename" column:

[image]

Created pipeline and performed dataflow activity by selecting created data flow and debug it

[image]

My output after debugging dataflow saved in the blob storage account with file name as inut file name

[image]